Gradle and Quarkus version Upgrade broke cucumber test suite ''No tests found for given includes:''
I have a cucumber test suite, which was working fine until gradle 7.6 version and Quarkus 3.5.3 version.
Once I upgrade to gradle 8.6 and Quarkus version 3.8.4 my cucumber tests are not recognized by gradle command.
If I switch to run the test suite with IntelliJ idea the tests get detected and works absolutely fine.
Below is my CucumberTest class.
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "engine.job.mock")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}

build.gradle.kts configs are as below
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
    if (requested.group == "org.junit.platform") {
      useVersion("1.10.2")
      because("quarkus brings in its own junit platform version that can override bom")
    }
  }

}


testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.18.0"))
testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-engine")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")  


tasks.withType<Test> {
  // Work around. Gradle does not include enough information to disambiguate
  // between different examples and scenarios.
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testLogging {
    events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
  }
}


The gradle command which I am running is as below.
gradle -p modules/abc :engine:test --tests "engine.job.mock.RunCucumberTest" -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m --stacktrace

The error which I am getting on command run
Execution failed for task ':engine:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [engine.job.mock.RunCucumberTest](--tests filter)

I went through all the blog posts on this issue and tried different suggested solution but nothing worked in this case.

Do your dependencies converge? Would suggest using the JUnit BOM to keep that part consistent. Also have you tried isolating the problem to the upgrade of Gradle or Quarkus?
